# Escaping the Infinite Blackboard

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

You wake up in a world with an infinite blackboard and hear a voice. "Let's play a little game. In front of you is a infinite blackboard. You may create a new number by adding a power of $2$ to an existing number, or taking two preexisting numbers $a, b$ and writing down $a \mod b.$ If you wish to escape, you will have to write down a number of my choosing subject to these rules, but I have to warn you that the number is going to be very large. How large? Let me put it this way: It's $G+T$ where $G$ is [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) and $T =$ [TREE(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem). Right now, only $0$ is written on the board. I think that should be a good place to start."

"I almost forgot to mention! Just as a little bonus, I've given you a magic machine. If you select $x$ and describe an algorithm for computing a non-negative integer $k,$ it will run the algorithm for you and write $x+2^k$ on the board in a blink of an eye - $100$ milliseconds. If you select numbers $a, b,$ it will instantly compute and write down $a \mod b$ for you, again taking $100$ ms. You can sit back and tell it to repeatedly increment by $1,$ but I'm sure you'll be driven insane long before you can get out of here. Good luck!"

Clarifications:

1. $a \mod b$ is a value in $[0, b).$ More precisely, if $a = pb+q$
   where $0 \le q < b,$ then $a \mod b = q.$
2. The machine does not have any powers beyond those described. You cannot have it start incrementing by $1,$ and then tell it to put you to sleep and wake you when it's finished.
3. You must write down the exact number, not a larger number that contains $G+T$ among its digits.

Comment: What numbers are available at the very beginning? All the operations need at least one pre-existing number.

Comment: @TobyMak Only $0.$ Fixed now.

Comment: "If you wish to escape, you will have to write down a number of my choosing" - Surely you just write down, "G+T". Please say precisely what you mean by "write down".  Do you want all the digits?

Comment: @reinstate Monica You have to write down the number subject to the rules for writing down a new number described earlier. Fixed.

Comment: Must k be an integer? Must k be non-negative?

Comment: @boboquack $k$ must be a non-negative integer. I don't see how using any of $1/2, 1/4, 1/8, \dots$ will help you anyways. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since there seems to be no limit on the algorithm provided to compute the exponent - it will run any algorithm in 100ms - this can be done in just a few steps.

> $G$ and $T$ are already defined by algorithms, even though the algorithm for $T$ would be a brute-force search. So the machine can internally compute $G+T$ in 100ms, even though it can't write it down directly.

> Rather than focus on $G+T$, you can get the machine to write down any number as $2^m \bmod 5^n$ as long as $5^n$ is greater than your number, since 2 is a primitive root of any power of 5. The machine can easily compute $m$ and $n$ here, but can't easily write $5^n$ directly. There's one catch here though. If our target number is a multiple of 5, then it's not covered. However, in that case, you can use this algorithm to get one less than the target and add one to it, and you can ask the machine to test whether you need this step or not.

> $2^x \bmod 2^x-5 = 5$, and this can be raised to an arbitrary power so that $2^{nx} \bmod 2^x-5 = 5^n$ as long as $5^n < 2^x-5$, so pick a large enough $x$. Now, the machine can't easily write down $2^x-5$ either.

> $2^x-5 = 2^{x+1} \bmod 2^x+5$ and this the machine can write down in 5 steps. Then another 2 steps for $2^{nx}$ and the next mod operation. Then two more for $2^m$ and the last mod operation. Plus one step to determine if the target is a multiple of 5, and if so one more step to add 1. As an example take a target of 15. This is a multiple of 5, so our target is 14. $5^2=25>14$ so $n=2$ and $2^6 \bmod 5^2 = 14$. To get the $5^2$, $2^5-5=27>5^2$, so $x=5$ (coincidentally), and $2^{10} \bmod 27 = 25$. Finally, $2^6 \bmod 2^5+5 = 27$.

Thanks to boboquack and Gareth McCaughan for completing the proof.

Comment: It's not even known that there are infinitely many primes (with no further conditions on their form) with 2 as a primitive root.

Comment: Is it known that there are infinitely many numbers with a primitive root of 2? There's nothing in this that needs it to be a prime. (I can't find many good resources on what's currently known about primitive roots beyond the basics covered by Wikipedia and Mathworld, if you have any good references.)

Comment: If there are only finite numbers with a primitive root of 2, or those numbers turn out to never involve just a handful of 1 bits, you can also generalize this approach by adding more bits to left side of the mod too.

Comment: Ah, nice -- if 2 is a primitive root mod p then "usually" it's a primitive root mod each p^k. This seems like it might be usable, maaybe? (To be more concrete: 2 is a primitive root mod any power of 5.)

Comment: That works out then. You just need the machine to pick any power of 5 bigger than G+T with a reasonably small number of 1s in its binary expansion, although looking at the binary expansion of some of those powers and there's clearly still some work to do to prove that any such number would have significantly fewer 1s.

Comment: I don't see any good reason to believe that there's a power of 5 bigger than G+T with fewer than, say, G ones in its binary expansion. Do you?

Comment: For just powers of 5, no, not particularly. For any number with a primitive root of 2 though? Much harder to guess. (Though trying some numbers out, it seems that most powers of primes are surprisingly, consistently close to 50/50 1s and 0s.)

Comment: I note that if you can find a way to construction 2^k-5 efficiently for large k, then for any n choose a k>log_2(5)n and then 2^(nk) mod 2^k-5 would be 5^n.

Comment: Oh and right 2^(k+1) mod 2^k+5 = 2^k-5 completing the solution

Comment: ... assuming G+T is not divisible by 5. How could we deal with this now? Then we need to construct 2^m5^n efficiently for the general case, but that’s a pretty simple modification on the above power of 5 construction (just multiply all involved numbers by 2^m)

Comment: You can hack the 5|G+T case pretty easily. First ask the machine to write down 2^0 if 5|G+T and 2^1 if not. If 5|G+T then derive G+T-1 instead and then ask the machine to add 1 to it.

Comment: Oh. It took me a while to grasp @boboquack 's comments, but yeah, altogether that should work. Let me see if I can write the full thing up.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to like this, but:

"OK, machine, listen up. I'm going to describe an algorithm for you, and it's a little bit complicated. First of all, let me define a *Turing machine* for you, along with a simple numerical representation for what's called a Turing machine's *state table*. [Do this. I promise I can.] And now let me define for you the notions of *formal system*, *proof*, and *Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory*. [Do this. Again, I promise I can.] Note that in the language of ZF set theory we can formalize the notion of Turing machine, and the proposition that a given machine halts. Now consider all possible finite strings in the language of ZF set theory. Some of them are mathematical proofs whose conclusion is of the form "The Turing machine with such-and-such state table, when run with an initially blank tape, eventually halts with the tape containing some number N." and obviously you can recognize those purely syntactically. So, say that a number $n$ is *good* if it's the representation of the state table of a Turing machine for which there is such a proof of length at most G+T steps. In this case, write $N(n)$ for the number $N$ it computes. OK so far? Now, I want you to enumerate all finite sequences of positive integers, and for each one I want you to simulate what you would do with a certain sequence of instructions derived from that sequence of integers. The integer $2^a3^b$, where $b$ is good, means "write down the $a$th number on the board plus $2^{N(n)}$. The integer $2^a5^b$ means "write down the $a$th number on the board modulo the $b$th number on the board". Other integers mean "do nothing". Still following? Splendid. So you need to do this for all finite sequences of positive integers, ordered by total length of all the integers and however you like subject to that. And the *first* time you find one of these sequences for which the simulated board ends up with G+T written on it, you then need to find the smallest power of 2 whose base-10 digits *begin* with an encoding of that sequence of numbers, defined as follows: encode $2^a3^b$ as 10A0B0 and $2^a5^b$ as 20A0B0 where A,B are derived from a,b by writing those numbers in base 7 and adding 3 to all their digits, and then concatenate everything to gether. Finally, when you've got that power of 2, please add that power of 2 to the 0 that's actually on the board and write down the result for me."

100ms later, I have on the board what may be a fairly monstrous number, but its digits *begin* with instructions telling me a nice efficient way (if there is one) to get the machine to put G+T on the board.

Obviously this isn't really in the spirit of the thing, but it definitely works :-).

(I do have some hazy ideas for how to do it better, but I have other things I need to do today so probably someone else will solve this properly before I do. That's OK.)

Discussion in comments has made it clear that what I wrote above isn't as clear as one might like, so let me explain in more detail what's going on; hopefully that will clarify both why it *works* and why it *obviously isn't remotely what the question is looking for*.

Our machine is terrifyingly powerful; it can perform any calculation we demand. But it has this annoying restriction that, in effecy, it can only output powers of 2 when it does it. Clearly the *intended* approach is to have it use that terrifying power to calculate something (or some *things*) from which G+T can be derived in a fairly simple way using the "adding powers of 2" and "modulus" operations we have. My approach will end up doing that, but it begins with a surely-unintended exploitation of the machine's power.

I want to get the machine to *solve the puzzle* for me. That is, to work out a short sequence of operations I can instruct it to perform, which has the result that we end up with G+T on the board. And I want to do it in a way that works even though the terrifying algorithmic power can only be used to generate powers of 2.

Well, solving the puzzle is itself an algorithmic matter! That is, we can set the machine to searching through all possible sets of instructions I could give it, in something like order of complexity, until it finds a set of instructions such that after performing them G+T is on the board.

There are three difficulties. First, is that *really* an algorithmic matter? Second, how can I express it in terms the machine can make any sense of? Third, how can I make use of the answer when the machine can only perform arbitrary calculations *whose answer is a power of 2*?

The answer to the first question is: yes, provided what I ask the machine to search through is *provably terminating algorithms* rather than just *algorithms that do in fact terminate*, because one can enumerate proofs mechanically.

The answer to the second question is: by casting my question in purely algorithmic form, which requires me to explain explicitly what an algorithm is and what a proof is, so that I can get the machine to enumerate *proofs* that *algorithms* terminate.

The answer to the third question is: by exploiting the fact that the puzzle involves an actual physical blackboard on which numbers are actually written -- I assume in base 10, but one could adapt this to any other reasonable system. So when the machine has found a procedure that will generate G+T, I get it to write down a number whose base-10 representation *begins* with a description of the procedure it found.

With all this understood, a fourth question arises: How do I make sure the procedure the machine finds is short enough that I can actually perform it? The algorithm described above was intended (it had a bug; see below) to have it enumerate sequences of algorithms in (more or less) order of the length of the *shortest proofs that the algorithms terminate*, which will produce procedures with short termination proofs, which isn't quite the same thing. I bet that this *would* actually produce something manageable, but what I really want is enumeration in order of the length of the algorithms' *descriptions* rather than of their *termination proofs*. This is more difficult because one can't enumerate *terminating algorithms* as such. But if we're prepared to accept, say, only algorithms that can be proved to terminate with proofs using no more than G+T steps -- I'm prepared to bet that we don't need more than that, because otherwise the puzzle would be unfair -- then we can do that just as easily.

And in fact I notice, on rereading my description of the algorithm, that I slipped up and wrote something intermediate between those two things, which is actually uncomputable. So I'm fixing it up the *second* way, so that now it looks for simplest algorithms (meaning smallest Turing machine) with termination proofs no longer than G+T, instead of looking for shortest termination proofs.

So, to be clear about what I actually do: I give the machine the instructions above, with the gaps filled in. I wait 100ms. The blackboard now contains a (presumably quite large, but not too monstrous) power of 2. The *digits* of this power of 2, reading from the left, contain explicit instructions specifying a sequence of things to ask the machine to do, each step being one of the two kinds permitted. So I read this number and issue the machine with those instructions.

A few details: (1) Although I said $2^a3^b$ and $2^a5^b$ when describing how to encode the procedure, actually that would be painful to decode. Better to make it a digit-concatenation thing like I did for the overall sequence. (2) When following the procedure the machine has found for me, I need to remember that there's now one more number on the blackboard than before I started. (3) Of course you could invalidate this whole approach by replacing the blackboard with, say, a computer memory accessible to the machine but not to me.

Comment: How do you plan to reach $G+T$ from the power of $2$ you just asked for? Your "nice efficient way" seems to involve performing an insanely large number of steps after you obtain the power of $2.$ In fact, I suspect whatever operations you haven't described yet will take longer than asking the machine to repeatedly increment by $1.$

Comment: *I* don't need to plan! The machine is doing all the planning for me :-). I will reach G+T from the power of 2 it gave me by _following the instructions encoded into the power of 2 it hands me_.

Comment: (I should maybe say that it's known, and fairly easy to prove, that every string of base-10 digits occurs at the beginning of _some_ power of 2, so that "the smallest power of 2 ..." at the end is guaranteed to exist.)

Comment: And no, none of what I have described will take _anywhere remotely like_ as long as just asking the machine to keep incrementing by 1. The bits I put in square brackets are omitted only because they're standard and not very interesting as far as solving this puzzle goes. It would take less than, let's say, an hour to fill in all the details, assuming -- as I think we have to -- that the machine is capable of understanding anything expressed explicitly and algorithmically.

Comment: I'm talking about all the steps that you need to take after you have this massive power of $2.$ What modulus are you going to use, and what new numbers are you going to introduce? You want to write down $G+T$ exactly, not write down a larger number that has $G+T$ in its digits. Else, there is an easier solution using Dirichlet's irrational approximation theorem and the irrationality of $\log_{10} 2.$

Comment: I don't think you've understood my solution. The procedure I describe is a way of getting the machine in the puzzle to _solve the puzzle_, because if there is anything I can do that provably works (i.e., all the algorithms I ask the machine to use do in fact provably terminate) then a short procedure that provably works is findable algorithmically. Hang on, instead of trying to explain this in comments I'll try to make my answer clearer.

Comment: ... OK, done. For the avoidance of doubt, I do understand that my answer is cheaty and not in the spirit of the question as intended. But I'm pretty sure it does work. (The original version had a bug, though. I've fixed it now.)

Comment: Alright. I see where you're going with this now, but if you wanted to cheat, there would be a much simpler answer. There exists a solution that takes some finite amount of time $t$ (repeatedly incrementing takes time $(G+T)/10$ for example). Have the machine simulate another blackboard plus itself running an algorithm in a fixed programming language. Run strings in the language sorted by length and then lexicographical order that succesfully compile, and as they are running, measure the amount of time that the simulated machine would spend.

Comment: Continued: If it goes past $t$ seconds, stop and move onto the next string. Halt after inspecting all strings with length $\le L$ for some constant $L,$ and then choose the one which has the shortest running time. Encode the string in base $2$ as $s$ and then find a power of $2$ beginning with $\overline{2s2}.$ After the machine now writes down that power of $2,$ you recover the string by finding the first and second $2$ in the number, translate back into the programming language, and then repeat those instructions to the machine.

Comment: The problem here is that this solution (and your solution unless I'm mistaken) assumes that a short solution exists, i.e. you can take $L = 10^9$ and there will be a solution that has less than a billion characters and requires only a small amount of steps. Of course, such a solution exists because the solution that I inteded will appear somewhere in list and it's runtime will be short, but that means you're relying on the existence of the intended solution for your solution to work.

Comment: Yup, I agree that there's something quite improper about relying on the existence of a reasonable solution in order to solve the problem. That's one of the reasons why my answer begins "You're not going to like this"! Possibly worse, it relies on the existence of a _provably working_ solution; perhaps one could construct a puzzle of this sort where the solution depends on, say, the consistency of ZFC, which more or less everyone believes in but is necessarily unprovable within that system.

Comment: I think your "much simpler" solution also works but it feels extra-naughty to have the machine explicitly simulate _itself_ at a much faster speed than the machine itself runs. (I don't think that means it _doesn't work_ because everything the machine does is computable, even if not efficiently computable, so one could rephrase this solution in terms that don't make explicit reference to the machine at all.)